# Tire Durability

Tags: tire, innertube

I bike a lot but I live in a neighborhood where there are a lot of sharp foreign objects on the ground. My bike's inner tube pops way too often for it to be practical to bike anymore and I don't want to just give up biking.

I read about putting slime in your tube to make it more durable but it only works with schrader tubes (my back tire is a schrader but my front tire is a presta).

Are there any other methods that are durable enough to withstand nails, glass, and pretty much any other foreign object that could be lying around? (unconventional ideas are welcome like maybe filling up my tube with sand idk?)

Comment: Have you tried puncture resistant tires? I've heard those are nice - https://www.schwalbe.com/en/tour-reader/marathon-plus.html though didn't used it myself, too expensive

Comment: I'm not a lover of slime as in the past I've had to replace the tube or use a new valve where slime blocks them up. I found going with a tire that has decent puncture protection was the better option, they may be slightly more expensive but should reduce the amount of punctures. Slime is only good for small pin hole punctures also, it won't offer any protection against a 1" gash

Comment: Yep, puncture-resistant tires.  And, of course, keep your tires properly inflated.

Comment: This is a duplicate question. However, since the first question was asked and answered, the technology for performance bike tires has advanced enough that tubeless tires are a possible solution, and they aren't discussed that much in the other answer. The thing is, tubeless is much more involved than tubes and tires. People who are into performance MTB or gravel bikes seem to find the tradeoffs to be fine. For performance road bikes, the advantage is a lot less clear. Assuming the OP mainly commutes, it's possible tubeless is an answer.

Comment: @WeiwenNg That's good information, it would be better added into your own answer on the linked question; we mark them as duplicates so that all the information ends up in the same place, not separated out